# Why are simplicial complexes modules?

Tags: homology-cohomology, simplicial-complex

When a simplicial complex is viewed as a R-module (such as appears in an exact sequence), what is the corresponding ring R and the Abelian group M?

Comment: They are not modules. Why do you think they are?

Comment: From my textbook, a chain complex C is a diagram of R-modules and module homomorphisms of the form $\partial_n : C_n \rightarrow C_{n-1}$ such that $\partial_n \partial_{n+1} = 0$.

Comment: Chain complexes and simplicial complexes are different kinds of objects.

Comment: In singular homology, a chain complex is formed from the Abelian group of n-simplexes, right?

Comment: I just want to understand how the notion of "modules" arises from the simplexes.